# How to print trailing spaces in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print some data like this:

```
John       22
Shakib     25
Ponting    28
```

Here i need to print some trailing spaces after the name.

I did this following way:

```
char *name[]={"John", "Shakib", "Ponting"};
int age[]={22, 25, 28};
int n=3;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%s",name[i]);
    int cnt=10;  // I need trailing spaces upto 10th column
    int len=strlen(name[i]);
    cnt-=len;
    while(cnt)
    {
        printf(" ");
        cnt--;
    }
    printf("%d\n",age[i]);
}
```

Is there any other way to print trailing spaces without using loop?

Comment: you can emit tabs (\t)

Comment: If you read the `printf` documentation (e.g. `man 3 printf`), this is explained rather well in the sections dealing with field width, precision, and alignment/justification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To print `trailing spaces` you can use either

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf("%-10s%d\n", name[i], age[i]);
```

or

```
int cnt = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf("%-*s%d\n", cnt, name[i], age[i]);
```

Comment: Sweet and simple, but I'll toss in a minor idea:  Insure name and age are separated with `int cnt = 10-1; printf("%-*s %d\n", cnt, name[i], age[i]);`  (Added space).  If the length of `name[i]` matches or exceeds `cnt` in the original answer, no separator is seen.  By explicitly having a space in the format (and making `cnt` one less) output is the same - unless the  `name[i]` is longer than expected - in which case there is always a space separator.

Comment: @chux You are right. But here maximum name size may be less than 10. So it won't be a problem, because OP need the age from 11th column.